# Custom gradle plug-ins appear "Error: (2, 0), Could not get unknown property 'com' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Tags: android

When developing the Gradle plug-in for the current project:

1. the new Module name must be BuildSrc
2. no resources directory is required.

Among them, the build.gradle content is:
[image: build.gradle]

the TinPlugin content is:
[image: TinPlugin]

Then, in module app,build.gradle adds "apply plugin: com.tin.TinPlugin", the problems during the operation of:

> Could not get unknown property 'com' for project ':app' of type
>   org.gradle.api.Project.

Could you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't anyone have this problem?